# Fixing two parameters to get three solutions to a set of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a curve given implicitly by

```
F[x_, y_] = 
  x^4 + x^3 y (-2 - 4 α) + y^4 α^2 (1 + α)^2 + d1 + y*d2 
   + x(-2y^3 α(1+α)(1+2α)+y(-1-2α+(1+2α)t2^2/t3^2) 
   + y^2 (2(1+2α)/t3 + (1+2α)t2/t3))
   + x^2 (1 + y^2 (1+6α+6α^2) - t2^2/t3^2 + y(-2-t2)/t3) 
   + y^3(-1-2α-2α^2 - α(1+α)t2)/t3 
   + y^2(1-t2 - α(1+α)t2^2 + α(1+α)t3^2)/t3^2 == 0
```

I want to set the coefficients $d_1$ and $d_2$ such that the system of equations

$\qquad F(x,y)=0,\ F_x(x,y)=0,\  F_y(x,y)=0$

has three solutions in $x$ and $y$ which will depend on $\alpha, t_2, t_3$.

Is there a good way of going about this without fixing $t_2, t_3$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: Do not use underscores in your variables (e.g. `d_1`); it will make things more difficult for you here.

Comment: Also, there's a closing bracket missing somewhere.

Comment: I think i may have corrected it

Comment: I can still see a `t_3` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
F[x_, y_] = x^4 + x^3 y (-2 - 4 α) + y^4 α^2 (1 + α)^2 +
   d1 + y*d2 + x (-2 y^3 α (1 + α) (1 + 2 α) +
      y (-1 - 2 α + (1 + 2 α) t2^2/t3^2) +
      y^2 (2 (1 + 2 α)/t3 + (1 + 2 α) t2/t3)) +
   x^2 (1 + y^2 (1 + 6 α + 6 α^2) - t2^2/t3^2 + y (-2 - t2)/t3) +
   y^3 (-1 - 2 α - 2 α^2 - α (1 + α) t2)/t3 +
   y^2 (1 - t2 - α (1 + α) t2^2 + α (1 + α) t3^2)/
     t3^2;

eqns = {F[x, y] == 0, D[F[x, y], x] == 0, D[F[x, y], y] == 0} //
   FullSimplify[#, t3 != 0] &;
```

Since you have three equations, only two variables of `{α, t1, t2}`are independent. In addition to solving for `d1` and `d2` you must also solve for one of `{α, t1, t2}`. Using `α`,

```
sol = Assuming[t3 != 0, Solve[eqns, {d1, d2, α}] // FullSimplify]

(* {{d1 -> (y^2 (4 (-2 + t2 - t3) (-2 + t2 + t3) + 8 (-2 + t2) t3 y + 
      3 t3^2 y^2))/(16 t3^2), 
  d2 -> -((y (8 + 2 t2^2 - 6 t3 y + t2 (-8 + 3 t3 y) + t3^2 (-2 + y^2)))/(
    4 t3^2)), α -> -(1/2) + x/y}, {d1 -> ((t2^2 - t3^2)^2 - 
    t2 (8 + t2) t3^2 y^2 - 8 t3^3 y^3)/(4 t3^4), 
  d2 -> ((2 + t2) (t2 - t3) (t2 + t3) + t2 (8 + t2) t3 y + 6 t3^2 y^2)/(
   2 t3^3), α -> (
   t3^2 (2 x - y) y - Sqrt[
    t3^2 y^2 (2 t2^2 + 2 t2 t3 y + t3 (4 y + t3 (-2 + y^2)))])/(
   2 t3^2 y^2)}, {d1 -> ((t2^2 - t3^2)^2 - t2 (8 + t2) t3^2 y^2 - 
    8 t3^3 y^3)/(4 t3^4), 
  d2 -> ((2 + t2) (t2 - t3) (t2 + t3) + t2 (8 + t2) t3 y + 6 t3^2 y^2)/(
   2 t3^3), α -> (
   t3^2 (2 x - y) y + Sqrt[
    t3^2 y^2 (2 t2^2 + 2 t2 t3 y + t3 (4 y + t3 (-2 + y^2)))])/(2 t3^2 y^2)}} *)
```

Verifying

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}, {True, True, True}} *)
```

**EDIT:** `Solve` for `{d1, d2, t3}` and they will be functions of `{x, y, t1, t2, α}`

```
sol2 = Assuming[t3 != 0, Solve[eqns, {d1, d2, t3}] // FullSimplify]

(* {{d1 -> (1/(
   2 t2^4))(t2^4 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)) (2 x^2 - 
        2 x (y + 2 y α) + y^2 (1 + 2 α (1 + α))) - 
     t2 y^3 Sqrt[
      4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
       t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
          y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] + 
     2 y^3 (2 y + Sqrt[
        4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
         t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
            y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))]) + 
     t2^3 y (x^2 Sqrt[
         4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
          t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
             y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] + 
        y (-2 + y^2 + 
           y α (1 + α) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] - 
           x (1 + 2 α) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))])) + 
     t2^2 y (y^3 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)) + 
        2 x^2 Sqrt[
         4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
          t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
             y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] + 
        y (2 + 8 x^2 - 
           2 x (1 + 2 α) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))]) + 
        y^2 (-8 x (1 + 2 α) + (1 + 2 α (1 + α)) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))]))), 
  d2 -> -(1/(
    2 t2^4))(t2^2 (4 - 4 t2 + (12 + (-4 + t2) t2) x^2) y - 
      t2^2 (12 + (-4 + t2) t2) x y^2 (1 + 2 α) + 
      y^3 (8 + t2^2 (t2 + 12 α (1 + α) - 
            4 t2 α (1 + α) + t2^2 α (1 + α))) + 
      2 t2^2 x^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
      t2^3 x^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
      2 t2^2 x y Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
      t2^3 x y Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
      4 y^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
      2 t2 y^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
      t2^2 y^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
      4 t2^2 x y α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
      2 t2^3 x y α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
      2 t2^2 y^2 α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
      t2^3 y^2 α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
      2 t2^2 y^2 α^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
      t2^3 y^2 α^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
        4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))]), 
  t3 -> -((2 t2^2)/((2 + t2) y + 
     Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
      4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))]))}, {d1 -> (1/(
   2 t2^4))(t2^4 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)) (2 x^2 - 
        2 x (y + 2 y α) + y^2 (1 + 2 α (1 + α))) + 
     t2 y^3 Sqrt[
      4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
       t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
          y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] - 
     2 y^3 (-2 y + Sqrt[
        4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
         t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
            y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))]) + 
     t2^3 y (-x^2 Sqrt[
         4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
          t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
             y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] + 
        y (-2 + y^2 - 
           y α (1 + α) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] + 
           x (1 + 2 α) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))])) + 
     t2^2 y (y^3 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)) - 
        2 x^2 Sqrt[
         4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
          t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
             y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))] + 
        2 y (1 + 4 x^2 + 
           x (1 + 2 α) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))]) - 
        y^2 (8 x (1 + 2 α) + (1 + 2 α (1 + α)) Sqrt[
            4 y^2 + 4 t2 y^2 + 
             t2^2 (4 + 8 x^2 - 8 x (y + 2 y α) + 
                y^2 (1 + 8 α (1 + α)))]))), 
  d2 -> (1/(2 t2^4))(-t2^2 (4 - 4 t2 + (12 + (-4 + t2) t2) x^2) y + 
     t2^2 (12 + (-4 + t2) t2) x y^2 (1 + 2 α) + 
     y^3 (-8 - 
        t2^2 (t2 + 12 α (1 + α) - 4 t2 α (1 + α) +
            t2^2 α (1 + α))) + 
     2 t2^2 x^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
     t2^3 x^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
     2 t2^2 x y Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
     t2^3 x y Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
     4 y^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
     2 t2 y^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
     t2^2 y^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
     4 t2^2 x y α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] - 
     2 t2^3 x y α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
     2 t2^2 y^2 α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
     t2^3 y^2 α Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
     2 t2^2 y^2 α^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))] + 
     t2^3 y^2 α^2 Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
       4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))]), 
  t3 -> (2 t2^2)/(-(2 + t2) y + 
    Sqrt[(2 + t2)^2 y^2 + 
     4 t2^2 (1 + 2 (x - y α) (x - y (1 + α)))])}} *)
```

However, there are only two sets of solutions

```
Length[sol2]

(* 2 *)
```

Both sets of solutions satisfy the equations

```
eqns /. sol2 // Simplify

(* {{True, True, True}, {True, True, True}} *)
```

Comment: This isn't precisely what I was thinking of. I wanted to choose d1 and d2 to be functions of $t1$, $t2$, and possible $\alpha$ and constants with respect to $x$ and $y$ such that there are three solutions in $x$ and $y$ to eqns.

Comment: @Aran - if you want to remove dependence on `x` and `y` you will need to provide two additional equations.